# Is weak convergence in $H^1$ invariant by translations?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $f_n\rightharpoonup 0$ weakly in $H^1$ and let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb{R}^d$. Is it true that $f_n(\cdot+x_n)\rightharpoonup 0$ weakly in $H^1$?.

Edit: if in addition $f_n\rightarrow0$ also strongly in $L^p$, $2\le p<2^*$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

No: Take any function $f\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $0\neq v\in \mathbb{R}^d$. Define $f_n:=f(\cdot +nv)$, then $f_n\rightharpoonup 0$, but with $x_n=-nv$, the sequence $f_n(\cdot +x_n)=f$ for all $n$.